# How to parse custom roster query response in Android XMPP client with SMACK

Tags: java, android, xmpp, smack

As for now I have very little understanding of XMPP and SMACK in general so please excuse me if my questions are imprecise.

Upon login I receive packet with roster that looks as follows:

```
<iq id="8CiUQ-1" type="result">
    <query xmlns="jabber:iq:roster">
    <item jid="625126126@saomeapp-test.cloudapp.net" name="Aziez" subscription="both" msgblock="none"/>
    <item jid="547657221@saomeapp-test.cloudapp.net" name="Kmil" subscription="both" msgblock="none"/>
    <item jid="553269257@saomeapp-test.cloudapp.net" name="grzegorz" subscription="both" msgblock="none"/>
    <item jid="683494364@saomeapp-test.cloudapp.net" name="Wiktor2" subscription="both" msgblock="none"/>
    <item jid="602914857@saomeapp-test.cloudapp.net" name="Art" subscription="both" msgblock="none"/>
    <item jid="634926524@saomeapp-test.cloudapp.net" name="ml" subscription="both" msgblock="none"/>
    </query>
</iq>
```

I know this because I can see this packet printed to my logcat under SMACK tag.

I need to access `msgblock` parameter. `org.jivesoftware.smack.RosterEntry` class will not have a getter for `msgblock` parameter as it is custom for this server implementation (I suppose). How do I access `msgblock` parameter then?

Here is what I tried:

I called: `mConnection.addPacketListener(new RosterPacketListener(), new RosterPacketFilter());` where `mConnection` is an instance of `org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection;`.

Filter looks like this:

```
    private class RosterPacketFilter implements PacketFilter{

        @Override
        public boolean accept(Packet packet) {
            return packet instanceof RosterPacket;
        }
    }
```

Listener:

```
private class RosterPacketListener implements PacketListener {

    @Override
    public void processPacket(Packet packet) {
        Log.d("tag", packet.toXML());
    }
}
```

The part that I completely don't understand is that the output for `Log.d("tag", packet.toXML());` does not contain the `msgblock` parameter. How do I access `msgblock` parameter in my roster?

Comment: `msgblock` appears like a non-standard attribute. You shouldn't depend on those. And if you where the one who invented it, then you shouldn't invent those.

Comment: @Flow: Exactly so, [as per documentation](http://xmpp.org/rfcs/rfc3921.html#roster) roster item does not contain this parameter. Unfortunately I wasn't me who added this so I am looking for a way around this problem.

Comment: Note that RFC3121 is deprecated, you should refer to RFC 6121. The only way to get the value of non-standard attributes is to patch internals of Smack

Comment: @Flow Is there a way to intercept incoming packets in their raw form before they get deserialised into Packet object of SMACK?

Comment: Eventually using a debugger. But I highly doubt that this is the way to go. The the answer is: No there is not. And you should not use those attributes.

Answer (score 0):

No need to add custom packet listener to connection object.

get all rosters from server

```
Roster roster = mConnection.getRoster();
// collection of RosterEntry from roster object
Collection<RosterEntry> entries= roster.getEntries();

for(RosterEntry entry : entries)
{
    Log.i("RosterName", "Name : "+ entry.getName());
    Log.i("RosterName", "Name : "+ entry.getUser());
}
```